# Function inside a function is not a function and is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

**Overview**

I'm learning Angular and JHipster, and I'm trying to get the id of an object in a collection.

I'm trying to get the id using trackBy but I getting this error:

```
[Error] ERROR – TypeError: this.cargarElementosFoda is not a function. (In 'this.cargarElementosFoda(item.id)', 'this.cargarElementosFoda' is undefined)

    TypeError: this.cargarElementosFoda is not a function. (In 'this.cargarElementosFoda(item.id)', 'this.cargarElementosFoda' is undefined)trackIdcheckdiffngDoCheckcheckAndUpdateDirectiveInlinedebugCheckAndUpdateNodedebugCheckDirectivesFn(función anónima)checkAndUpdateViewcallViewActionexecEmbeddedViewsActioncheckAndUpdateViewcallViewActionexecComponentViewsActioncheckAndUpdateViewcallViewActionexecEmbeddedViewsActioncheckAndUpdateViewcallViewActionexecComponentViewsActioncheckAndUpdateViewcallWithDebugContextdetectChangesforEachtick(función anónima)onInvokerunnext(función anónima)__tryOrUnsubnext_nextnextnextemitcheckStableonLeaveonInvokeTaskrunTaskinvokeTaskinvokeTaskglobalZoneAwareCallback
        error
        View_PlanEstrategicoDetailComponent_1 (PlanEstrategicoDetailComponent.ngfactory.js:337)
        logError (core.js:12446)
        (función anónima)
        handleError (core.js:1922)
        run (zone.js:137)
        tick (core.js:5374)
        (función anónima) (core.js:5210:110)
        onInvoke (core.js:4343)
        run (zone.js:137)
        next (core.js:5210:85)
        (función anónima) (core.js:3993)
        __tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:262)
        next (Subscriber.js:200)
        _next (Subscriber.js:138)
        next (Subscriber.js:102)
        next (Subject.js:64)
        emit (core.js:3985)
        checkStable (core.js:4312)
        onLeave (core.js:4379)
        onInvokeTask (core.js:4337)
        runTask (zone.js:187)
        invokeTask (zone.js:495)
        invokeTask (zone.js:1539)
        globalZoneAwareCallback (zone.js:1576)
```

I don't know why this is happening because all my other functions are working well.

**This is the TS component:**

```
      import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { JhiEventManager, JhiParseLinks, JhiAlertService } from 'ng-jhipster';

import { DiagnosticoFodaService } from 'app/entities/diagnostico-foda';
import { IPlanEstrategico } from 'app/shared/model/plan-estrategico.model';
import { IDiagnosticoFoda } from 'app/shared/model/diagnostico-foda.model';
import {IElementosDiagnosticoFoda} from 'app/shared/model/elementos-diagnostico-foda.model';
import { ElementosDiagnosticoFodaService } from 'app/entities/elementos-diagnostico-foda';
@Component({
    selector: 'sigem-plan-estrategico-detail',
    templateUrl: './plan-estrategico-detail.component.html'
})
export class PlanEstrategicoDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    planEstrategico: IPlanEstrategico; 
    diagnosticoFodas: IDiagnosticoFoda[];
    elementosDiagnosticoFodas : IElementosDiagnosticoFoda[];
    elementosFodas: IDiagnosticoFoda[];
    idPlan : number;

    constructor(
        private jhiAlertService: JhiAlertService, 
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
        private diagnosticoFodaService: DiagnosticoFodaService,
        private elementosDiagnosticoFodaService : ElementosDiagnosticoFodaService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(({ planEstrategico }) => {
            this.planEstrategico = planEstrategico;
            this.idPlan = planEstrategico.id; 
            this.cargarAnaliziFoda(this.idPlan);
        });

    }

    previousState() {
        window.history.back();
    }
    private onError(errorMessage: string) {
        this.jhiAlertService.error(errorMessage, null, null);
    }

    cargarAnaliziFoda(id){
        this.diagnosticoFodaService.findByPlan(id).subscribe(
            (res: HttpResponse<IDiagnosticoFoda[]>) => {
                this.diagnosticoFodas = res.body;   
            },
            (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message)
        );
    }
    cargarElementosFoda(id_foda){ 
        /*this.elementosDiagnosticoFodaService.findByFODA(id_foda).subscribe(
            (res: HttpResponse<IElementosDiagnosticoFoda[]>) => {
                this.elementosDiagnosticoFodas = res.body;   
                console.log(this.elementosDiagnosticoFodas);
            },
            (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message)
        );*/
    }
    trackId(index: number, item: IDiagnosticoFoda) {
        console.log('el id de este diagnostico foda es' + item.id);
        this.cargarElementosFoda(item.id); 
    }


}
```

**And HTML component:**

This is the part of the html where I call track by id

```
<ngb-panel  *ngFor="let diagnosticoFoda of diagnosticoFodas;trackBy: trackId">
<ng-template  ngbPanelTitle>
<span > Diagnostico FODA {{diagnosticoFoda.nombre}} 
</span>
</ng-template>
```

**Notes**

- I'm really new on Angular, TypeScript, and Jhipster.
- Please if I missed something important, let me know on the comment and I will added to the question.
- Im just trying to get the `diagnosticoFoda.id` so maybe is a better
  way that trackBy function.

Comment: Can  you show the full file which the code is in?

Comment: @AGhanima sorry, I update the quest with the full code.

Comment: We need to know where this is happening. I'm assuming something in your template is calling either trackId (which calls cargarElementosFoda) or cargarElementosFoda directly. But nothing from the code you've posted actually causes cargarElementosFoda to be called.

Comment: @NightCabbage yes, in the html template I have a Collapse and diferent ngb-panels for some many datas but the important here is the one with the FODA so let me add that to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The Problem

My guess is that an event handler is calling the `trackId` method. If we call a method from an event handler, the method no longer has its `this` bound to an instance of the class. With the `this` no longer bound to an instance of the class, the `cargarElementosFoda` method is undefined, which is what your error states.

### One Solution

Make `trackId` into [an arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) instead of a method. That will ensure that `this` is bound to an instance of the class even when the arrow function is called from an event.

```
trackId = (index: number, item: IDiagnosticoFoda) => {
    console.log('el id de este diagnostico foda es' + item.id);
    this.cargarElementosFoda(item.id); 
}
```

### More Details

Here is a simplified example with one event that calls an arrow function and another event that calls a method. Note that the method has `this` bound to the class only when it is called from an instance of that class.

```js
class Foo {

  someMethod() {
    console.log('someMethod:' + (this instanceof Foo));
  }

  someArrowFunction = () => {
    console.log('someArrowFunction:' + (this instanceof Foo));
  };
}

const foo = new Foo();

// when called from an instance of the class,
// both the arrow function and the method are bound to an instance of Foo
foo.someArrowFunction();
foo.someMethod();

// when not called from an event
// the arrow function remains bound to the instance of Foo
document
  .getElementById('btn1')
  .addEventListener("click", foo.someArrowFunction);

// when not called from an event
// the  method is no longer bound the instance of Foo
document
  .getElementById('btn2')
  .addEventListener("click", foo.someMethod);
```

```html
<button id="btn1">Invoke Arrow Function</button>
<button id="btn2">Invoke Method</button>
```

Comment: Thank you it was really instructive and solve my problem.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad to hear that it helped. That means a lot to me.

Comment: yes actually my teacher dint know was happened and he learn to, at the end I finish not using the track id to call the method but this stay like a reference in my long way to learn angular and typeScript so thank you for the time and examples.

Comment: What an impact! That's fun.